# Connecting in SSH in a Python script

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi, ip, raspberry-pi3

I am connected to a first Raspberry Pi (172.18.x.x) in  SSH and I would like to launch a script on the first RPI but the script is on another Raspberry Pi (192.168.x.x).
First, I did the configuration to connect without password to the second RPI from the first one.
When I am on the first one, I am launching this command :

```
ssh pi@192.168.x.x 'sudo python script_RPI2.py'
```

And this is working correctly, I can check the correct results but I would like to launch this script in another script on the first RPI. So, I put the previous command in the file : script_RPI1.py.
Then, I am launching the script : `sudo python script_RPI1.py`
And I got the following error :

```
 ssh pi@192.168.x.x 
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone has an idea concerning my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

How are you launching the script? What appears from the minimal information you gave is that you are trying or to do that command within the Python interactive interpreter or that you want to execute it in the interpreter and you forgot to surround it with quotes(") in order to make it as a string.

Try to explain a bit more please.

You want to run a bash command:

```
ssh pi@192.168.x.x 'sudo python script_RPI2.py'
```

you show do it in a .sh file as in the following example:

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh pi@192.168.x.x 'sudo python script_RPI2.py'
```

After saving this file just do ./name_of_file.sh, which will simply run your bash file in the terminal, if you want to run a python script that opens a terminal in another process and executes string that are terminal commands you should look at something like this:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ls"])
```

This will execute ls in another terminal process and return the result back to you. Please check what you want to actually do and decide on one of these paths.

Comment: I said that I am launching the script from the first RPI (172.18.x.x) with : `sudo python script_RPI1.py` and in this script, there is the command : `ssh pi@192.168.x.x 'sudo python script_RPI2.py'`It's not a problem of quotes because I got the same error with quotes. This is the code of script_RPI1.py : `#!/usr/bin/python

ssh pi@192.168.x.x 'sudo python script_RPI2.py'` If I removed 'sudo ...' in the script, I got the same error : `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Okay I think I understood, the line: `ssh pi@192.168.x.x 'sudo python script_RPI2.py'` isn't a valid python statement and you are trying to run it as such. Please just answer me this, do you prefer to launch it as a shell script on your machine or a python script that opens a terminal in a process and does the command?

Comment: In fact, in the file script_RPI1.py and script_RPI2.py, I got  many lines with Python coding, so it's better to continue in Python instead of bash shell. Meanwhile, is it possible to launch a bash script in a Python script ? In my case, I will create a file : script.sh composed with `#!/bin/sh

ssh pi@192.168.x.x 'sudo python script_RPI2.py'` in the first RPI and I will call  this script by `bash script.sh`  in script_RPI1.py. Is it possible ? If yes, I will try that tomorrow

Comment: i tried what I said below but it didn't work, I think `sudo bash script.sh` it's not a valid python statement

Comment: I also tried `from subprocess import call
call(["sudo python script_RPI2.py"])` in the file script_RPI1.py but it didn't work whereas it worked with just `ls`

Comment: So you seem quite confused, and I'm probably. not explaining myself correctly. `sudo bash script.sh` is a terminal command as well as the one you are trying to do within the quotes. Please explain exactly what you are trying to do, because I'm really not understanding what you want.

Comment: Ok right, so, on the first RPI, there are 3 sensors connected to it, I gathered the three Python scripts in one : script_RPI1.py. There is another sensor on the second RPI, the script to read the data is in Python too. My objective is to launch only one script from the first RPI and get back all the results from the different sensors. Now, I can launch script_RPI2.py from the first RPI by : ssh pi@192.168.x.x 'sudo python script_RPI2.py but I want to integer this command or a way to get the result in script_RPI1.py. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the entire answer and actually put some extra time on the code. The full solution for you to integrate will look something like the code below. Note that the code is setup in a way that you can define the host to connect to, along with the command you want to execute in the remote RPi

```
import subprocess
import sys

remoteHost="pi@192.168.x.x"
command="python /path/to/script.py"

ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % remoteHost, command],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
if result == []:
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
else:
    print result

yourVar = result   ### This is where you assign the remote result to a variable
```

Comment: This is the error message : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_RPI1.py", line 110, in <module>
    Flow_sensor = call(['ssh pi@192.168.x.x "sudo python /home/pi/script_RPI2.py"'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: I tried with you method by putting in the file script_RPI1.py : 'from subprocess import call
RPI2_Sensor = call(['ssh pi@192.168.x.x "sudo python /home/pi/script_RPI2.py"']) print (RPI2_Sensor)` The error message is below

Comment: I changed the entire answer and added some code that will allow you to easily insert the remote host and the command you want to execute, in this case your Python Script to get a value from a sensor. I hope it helps.

Comment: Your script is working properly but when I integer it in the whole file which is script_RPI1.py, I just got the result of your script, so I got the result of the sensor on the second RPi but I don't get the results of the others sensors on the first RPI

Comment: Did you try again? The code uses "Popen" rather than "call". Also, you need to include this whole piece of code inside your "script_RPI1.py". It was not included here so you will have to adjust indentations if needed along with the remote host data and the path to the script in the remote Pi.

Comment: Try using the flag "-i /path/to/identity.file" inside the command variable. This should remove the issue with having to login with a password. Also, edit your question to add the script you are running in RPI1. We may be able to help with the extra issues.